# Formtastic set class and id of form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How can I set the class and id attribute for the form element through semantic_form_for?

The following code:

```
<% semantic_form_for (@meetingsearch), :class => "new_meeting_search", :id => "meeting_search" do |f| %>
```

gives me:

```
<form action="/meetingsearches" class="formtastic meetingsearch" id="new_meetingsearch" method="post">
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should do what you need (untested):

```
<% semantic_form_for @meetingsearch, :html => { :class => "new_meeting_search", :id => "meeting_search" } do |f| %>
```

For clarification, `semantic_form_for` wraps around Rails' built in `form_for`, so this is exactly how you do it in [regular Rails forms also](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001604):

```
<% form_for @meetingsearch, :html => { class => "new_meeting_search", :id => "meeting_search" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: the key for me was using "html" instead of "input_html" as the key

Comment: They even have the feature documented: `TODO: document the "guessing" of input style` -.-